# I am using a Timer, to pull Data after clicking a button. I cannot stop the timer on multiple clicks

Tags: excel, vba

I just want to make it where if you press stop button the timer Ends.  This Sheet pulls hundreds of data points, and works great even added some If then solutions to prevent double clicking nightmare.  But in-between waiting for the original timer to stop you can duplicate the autotimer event by clicking again.

Thank you I been trying to figure this out for two days.  I have seen several solutions but none seem to work for me for my specific setup.

```
Option Explicit
Dim StopMacro1 As Boolean


Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 Worksheets("Unit 18 VIP 1").Activate

StopMacro1 = True

Range("V33").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Range("V33").Value = "OFF"
Range("V33").Font.Bold = True
Range("V33").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)

End Sub
Sub StopTimer1()

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:02:00"), "RunAll1", , False

End Sub

Sub SetStopMacro1()

If StopMacro1 = False Then


    StopTimer1

    Range("V33").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Range("V33").Value = "OFF"
    Range("V33").Font.Bold = True
    Range("V33").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)

    StopMacro1 = True
    Message1
    
Else

    Exit Sub
    
End If

End Sub
Sub SetStartMacro1()

Range("V33").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
Range("V33").Value = "ON"
Range("V33").Font.Bold = True
Range("V33").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
 
StopMacro1 = False
RunAll1

End Sub
Sub Message1()

'Calls up message box to alert user the stopped the Auto-Update
MsgBox "This sheet will no longer Auto-Update.  Press Start Button to update", vbCritical

End Sub
Sub macro_timer1()
'Questions the StopMacro has been set to off if so it will exit the repeating sub.
If StopMacro1 = True Then

Exit Sub

Else

'Tells Excel when to next run the macro.
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:02:00"), "RunAll1", , True

End If

End Sub
Sub RunAll1()
'Questions the StopMacro has been set to off if so it will exit the repeating sub.
If StopMacro1 = True Then
    
    Exit Sub

Else

Column_D1
Column_H1
Column_L1
Column_P1
Column_T1

'Starts the Macro_Timer
Call macro_timer1

End If

End Sub
```

So when I Click a button I assigned a macro SetStopMacro1

I want to Kill the timer

```
Sub Macro_Timer1()

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:02:00"), "RunAll1", , True
End Sub
```

So I added this

```
Sub StopTimer1()

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:02:00"), "RunAll1", , False

End Sub
```

When I run the code it freezes the program when I press stop for Sub StopTimer1, it says Run-time error '1004' ect..

Answer (score 0):

While I am fairly new to this I think I discovered the answer with a bit of help from reading [Francis Maltais](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5818579/francis-maltais) Post he made 6 years ago.

I see he declared the Timer as Dim.  So I did so similar, in excel VB.  Will past solution below and simplify the code without all extra.

Here is my header of Module

```
Option Explicit
'Sets the StopMacro1 as True / False Stores value 
Dim StopMacro1 As Boolean
'Stores date value for my timer
Dim MyTime1 As Date
```

Next wanted to add a value MyTime1 for when this book is opened.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 Worksheets("Unit 18 VIP 1").Activate

'Sets the Stopmacro1 to True to ensure its stopped.
StopMacro1 = True

'Calls the Sub SetMytime1 to create a value when Workbook is open
SetMytime1

'Enters formatting into Excel cells to ensure user knows its not auto-updating.
Range("V33").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Range("V33").Value = "OFF"
Range("V33").Font.Bold = True
Range("V33").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)

End Sub
```

I could have done this a bit different but figure its just easier to call it where needed.

```
Sub SetMytime1()
    'Places a 2 minute timer for Application.OnTime
    MyTime1 = Now + TimeValue("00:02:00")
    
End Sub
```

Now added another Sub to Stop the time event.

```
Sub StopTimer1()

'Stops the Auto-Update Clears timer
Application.OnTime MyTime1, "RunAll1", Schedule:=False

End Sub
```

So for my Stop button I used this sub.

```
Sub SetStopMacro1()

If StopMacro1 = False Then

    StopTimer1

    Range("V33").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Range("V33").Value = "OFF"
    Range("V33").Font.Bold = True
    Range("V33").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)

    StopMacro1 = True
    Message1
    
Else

    Exit Sub
    
End If

End Sub
```

For my Start Button I used this sub

```
Sub SetStartMacro1()

SetMytime1

Range("V33").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
Range("V33").Value = "ON"
Range("V33").Font.Bold = True
Range("V33").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
 
StopMacro1 = False
RunAll1

End Sub
```

For the Core RunAll calls about 130 cells of data not posting it but you get the idea.

```
Sub RunAll1()
'Questions the StopMacro has been set to off if so it will exit the repeating sub.
If StopMacro1 = True Then
    
    Exit Sub

Else

Column_D1
Column_H1
Column_L1
Column_P1
Column_T1

'Starts the Macro_Timer
Call macro_timer1

End If

End Sub
```

For my macro_timer1 I used this.

```
Sub macro_timer1()
'Questions the StopMacro has been set to off if so it will exit the repeating sub.
If StopMacro1 = True Then

Exit Sub

Else

MyTime1 = Now + TimeValue("00:02:00")
'Tells Excel when to next run the macro.
Application.OnTime MyTime1, "RunAll1"

End If

End Sub
```

That's about it.  All that combined prevents double Clicks and repeat timers and kills the original timer when stopped even if you press start again in less then the 2 min range.  Sorry a bit new at this, but took me forever to figure out how to get such a simple thing to work.  My VB and excel classes where 10 plus years ago lol.  I would love any tips or tricks to help simplify this process if able, or if you see any mistakes.  Thanks in advance :D